# HP HDX 16 wifi turns on and off randomly

Tags: windows-7, windows, wireless-networking

I've been having this problem recently with my HDX 16 and was wondering whether there was any driver updates that fix this problem or any 3rd party drivers that could help.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled across this page and figured I'd answer your question even though it's a bit old. I've got an HDX16 also and have the same issue. Apparently, you just need to get a new wifi card if it doesn't stop. I haven't had the issue in a while, and I'm about to upgrade to Windows 7, but I'm most likely going to order a new wifi card this summer for free since I have a warranty.